# Replace table head with search bar without adjusting the table body

Tags: angularjs, html, css, html-table, cross-browser

I am trying to implement search in an HTML table. The search bar, when active, should replace the table header. When I'm done the header should come back.

The JSFiddle for this can be seen [here](http://jsfiddle.net/anshukch/u9efrf30/17/)

The problem is when I switch to search mode, my table body readjusts, I believe this is because the header goes away then. Because, if I decide to keep my header intact, the problem is not there. How to go around it? We can't fix widths of the cells. But relative width (em and %) could be given.

Any help is appreciated. Please let me know if more info is required.

**HTML Code**

```
<div ng-app>
    <div ng-controller="SearchCtrl">
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr class="search" ng-show="showSearch()">
                <th colspan="3">
                    <input type="text" ng-model="searchStr" placeholder="Enter Name">        
                </th>
            </tr>
            <tr class="header" ng-hide="showSearch()">
<!-- If we were to show the header, the table doesn't readjust -->
<!--       <tr class="header"> -->
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Class</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="row in rows">
                <td>{{row.name}}</td>
                <td>{{row.age}}</td>
                <td>{{row.class}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <div class="search-control">
            <input class="btn-primary" type="submit" value="Show Search" ng-click="ifSearch = true">
            <input class="btn-primary" type="submit" value="Close Search" ng-click="ifSearch = false">
    </div>
        <div class="debug">
            You Searched for: {{searchStr}}    
        </div>
</div>
```

**CSS Code**

```
thead tr, tbody tr {
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    width: 100%;
}
th, td {
    padding: 10px;
}

.search-control, .debug {
    margin-top: 20px;
}
```

**AngularJS Code**

```
function SearchCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.ifSearch = false;
    $scope.searchStr = '';
    $scope.rows = [{
        name: 'John',
        age: 10,
        class: 6
    },{
        name: 'Anthony',
        age: 9,
        class: 4
    },{
        name: 'Xavier',
        age: 11,
        class: 8
    }]
    $scope.showSearch = function () {
        return $scope.ifSearch;
    };
}
```

**UPDATE**: I have added an answer for this problem [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48897513/2696209). But the problem in that is it's misbehaving in Chrome but working as expected in Firefox/Safari. In chrome the border under the search bar disappears. While it's there in the other browsers. Any ideas? Understanding this is more important to me than knowing how exactly to fix this problem!

Comment: Give it a relative width then?

Comment: @MarkBaijens It still doesn't work! I've updated the Fiddle with relative widths. The borders readjust.

Comment: I would try positioning he search bar absolutely.

Comment: @AnshuKumar Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/u9efrf30/49/

Comment: @MarkBaijens That works because you have given width of 3em to the last two tds of the row. For some reason, if I could not have this luxury and if 2em is my max limit, it won't work. But yes, your Fiddle works. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks Guys for your help!!! But I don't seem to figure out, while searching,  why the border for the first row doesn't appear in Chrome but does in Firefox and Safari? Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Since `display: none` for `th` was changing the width of the cells and readjusting it, `visibility: hidden` came to my rescue and then I also applied `position: absolute` to my search bar.

The updated fiddle can be found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/anshukch/u9efrf30/88/).

Comment: This solution has one caveat though. While searching, the border for the first row doesn't appear in Chrome but does in Firefox and Safari. Any idea?